# "virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable" using virtual env and anaconda

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda

I'm trying to start up a virtual env using virtualenv, am getting this error:

```
Already using interpreter /Users/pkilcrease/anaconda/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/Users/pkilcrease/anaconda'
New python executable in /Users/pkilcrease/.virtualenvs/bodega/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /Users/pkilcrease/.virtualenvs/bodega/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /Users/pkilcrease/.virtualenvs/bodega/bin/python3 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/pkilcrease/.virtualenvs' (should be '/Users/pkilcrease/.virtualenvs/bodega')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

The command I am running is `mkvirtualenv -a . --no-site-packages --python='which python3' -r requirements.txt bodega`

My `.bashrc` file currently looks like this:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/Users/pkilcrease/anaconda/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /Users/pkilcrease/anaconda/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
```

I have the feeling that there is some issue with anaconda and virtualenv which is causing the problem here, but not sure how to remedy that or if it's just a red herring.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a virtualenv instead of using a conda environment?

Comment: I was trying for consistency in dev environments with my team.... but I'm likely going to give up on that goal and just run with conda at this point.

Comment: Get them to switch to conda and everyone will be happy! :-)

Comment: I find this frustrating though because I used virtualenv yesterday with with anaconda at work, but on my personal laptop I get this error. I would expect some more consistency.

Answer (score 1):

If using a conda python executable, use `conda create --name {your_venv} python=3`  (note there is a `virtualenv` utility that comes with conda, but still use `conda create...` to make new virtual env's).

Otherwise, when using a version of python installed by the system package manager, create a virtual env using `virtualenv`, or preferably using the `virtualenvwrapper` utility `mkvirtualenv`. For example on Linux, the "system python" is `/usr/bin/python3`, `/usr/bin/python`, `/usr/bin/python2`, etc. Or, as it's clear you're on MacOS, that would likely be a python installed by `brew` (homebrew) or `port` (macports) in `/opt` or `/usr/local`.  You may have to install `virtualenvwrapper` in order to get `mkvirtualenv` (and `lsvirtualenv`, etc).

In short, if you're using anaconda python, stick with `conda` utils. Else, if  you're keeping your python free & open (as many of your corp IT data centers do), then use any of the various open utils like `mkvirtualenv`, etc.

Comment: Python's latest solution to managing virtual env's is `pipenv`. If you're using plain old normal python (which is generally recommended if you're on linux), then you'd now probably prefer to start using `pipenv`, unless already invested in one of the older techniques. If you're on mac or windows, then conda is probably still your best bet for installing/managing python -- and there, you can still use `conda` to manage your virtualenv's (but `pipenv` might have conda integration at some point). http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this may help people still looking at this question, but an easy fix:

```
conda install -y virtualenv
```